# Почему при старте скрипта из виртуального окружения запускаются два процесса python.exe?

Tags: python, virtualenv, venv

Если запустить python код и посмотреть список всех запущенных процессов, то мы увидим запущенный *python.exe* по адресу установки в систему(на который ссылается переменная окружения).

[image: скрин]

Однако если этот же код запустить через виртуальное окружение, например venv, то процессов *python.exe* уже будет два: один по адресу установки в систему, второй по адресу развёрнутого виртуального окружения.
[image: скрин]

Мне всегда казалось, что при создании виртуального окружения создаётся полноценная копия интерпретатора, который исполняется в соло как и установленный в систему. Как это работает и почему так происходит?

Comment: Что где как именно вы запускаете?

Comment: Что -> любой скрипт. Например пусть это будет бесконечный цикл с принтом. Где -> windows, командная строка. Как именно -> путь/до/интерпритатора путь/до/файла.py. Например python myscript.py. Если через venv, то сперва активация окружения

Comment: Что такое путь/до/интерпретатора? Какой смысл указывать путь при активированном окружении? И как было создано виртуальное окружение кстати?

Comment: Путь/до/интерпритатора значит то, что я могу написать просто 'python' и это будет ссылка к интерпретатору через переменную окружения. А могу руками указать полный путь и эти две записи будут эквивалентны. Какой смысл указывать -> никакого. Однако команды path_to_venv\activate.bat и далее python my_script.py эквивалентны path_to_venv\python.exe my_script.py, разве нет? Как создано - через PyCharm  или командой из терминала python -m venv venv, сути это не меняет

Comment: имхо виртуальный питон.ехе настраивает переменные окружения и запускает реальный питон в этом окружении. То есть работает как банальный батник. Потому и получается 2 процесса

Comment: @vitidev однако в линуксе он этого не делает. Поэтому остаётся вопрос — зачем он это делает в винде? Ну или наоборот, что позволяет питону не создавать второй процесс в линуксе?

Comment: @coffe_owl вы наверное не правильно установили пайтон или виртуальное окружение, если вы на химичили с переменными PATH, то вот вам и результат.

Comment: @andreymal ему достаточно симлинки и наличия файла pyvenv.cfg. Но в windows создание симлинки требует повышенных прав, а junction point тут не поможет, поэтому и создаются дополнительные ехешники. Если дропнуть эти ехешники и сделать симлинку руками, то будет один процесс в итоге

Comment: @Александр всё правильно, я у себя тоже смог увидеть два процесса